# tab to select drop-down input box

Tags: keyboard, web-browsing

In any web browser in Mac OS X, how can I choose a drop-down form input box using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key? When I need to input many forms including a drop-down box, I preferred to use <kbd>tab</kbd> key and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to move between input elements in Windows systems.

Why is it impossible in Mac, and how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have this set (it's not the default) in Keyboard Preferences

[image]